# Julia Circular Inclusion

Tags: julia

My goal: For a project, be able to include local files (part of the same project, same exact directory), trivially, possibly circularly.

In Julia, say I have the files:

FILE1.jl

```
module A

include("FILE2.jl")
using B

# Type annotations that need types from B

end
```

FILE2.jl

```
module B

include("FILE1.jl")
using A

# Type annotations that need types from A

end
```

In Julia (>v1), this results in an infinite loop. I have tried adding files to my loadpath so that I may directly use using or import, but it still can't find them.

What is the "Julian" way to include files within the same directory assuming circular dependencies, and are part of the same project? I see many posts saying something like, "if this is the case, your code is probably wrong", and I think that's just a silly claim to make.

Comment: Just to clarify: I think you're conflating two notions here. Modules are essentially namespaces. They haven't much to do with files: a single Julia source file can define several modules, or a single Julia module can have its implementation split into multiple  files. I'm mentioning this because you seem accustomed to Python, in which (AFAIU) there is most of the time a direct, one-to-one mapping between source files and modules. This, as well as other differences between Python and Julia, is mentioned in https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/noteworthy-differences/

Comment: Could you please explain why such circular dependencies arise? In other words, in which way do both files/modules depend on one another?

Comment: I updated the question for formatting and to better reflect what I'm trying to do. If I register my package with my current environment, will it be found without having to use include?

Comment: As an update - I do not want to have files which include multiple modules per file. Ultimately, I want a module to define one or a few abstract types, and then define some concrete structs which extend this type, as well as some methods. The concrete structs have fields which may rely on abstract types defined in other modules, and possibly circularly so.

Answer (score 5):

A common structure is to put all `include`s in one place, at the root of your project. [Flux.jl](https://github.com/FluxML/Flux.jl/blob/master/src/Flux.jl) is a good example.

People use `module` to subdivide their project if it is very large, but you don't need to! A large project can consist of a single module. I would suggest to only split a chunk of code into its own module if it makes sense as an *isolated* whole. (Others might have a different view on this!) But since you asked about circular references, it sounds like a single module better suits your situation.

Modules cannot contain circular references:

```
# will not work
module A
    import ..B: y
    x = 1
end
module B
    import ..A: x
    y = 1
end
```

This is not a problem with functions:

```
function a(x)
    if x < 1
        1
    else
        b(x-1) * 2
    end
end

function b(x)
    a(x)
end

b(10)
```

Functions can use types, functions, constants, modules that are defined *after* its own definition.

Comment: I still am lost. In FILE1.jl, I define some basic abstract types, all contained within module A. Now, I also have FILE2.jl. FILE2.jl has no modules (although this should not matter), just bare Julia code. In FILE2.jl, I want to define a concrete type which extends one of these abstract types from module A. At the end, I also want to include FILE2.jl within FILE1.jl. I do not want to directly store FILE2.jl within FILE1.jl.

Comment: This is a good strategy! In that case you are just splitting the code of module A into multiple files. So **inside** module A (before `end`), you do `include("FILE2.jl")`.

Comment: You should see `include(path)` as "take the text from `path`, and paste it here". In Python, folder structure equals module structure, in Julia you write module structure yourself (if you need it), `include` is just a copy-and-paste command.

Comment: Thank you for the help. How do I safely provide the abstract types to the scope of FILE2.jl without include("FILE1.jl"), which would call include("FILE2.jl"), inf loop..?

Comment: Files do not introduce a scope, you should really see `include` as a copy-paste command. This is why you need to `include` _inside_ the module: this makes the abstract types available in file 2.

Comment: Also be sure to use a Julia IDE like VS Code! These understand scope and will warn you if something is not accessible.

Comment: Is there any update to this? I still don't see a proper way to handle this circular inclusion. Please see my most recent comment stating what I'd like to do.

Comment: Update: I think the only way to solve this is to not use include. Instead, push files to the LOAD_PATH and only rely on using or import. include() still has a use case but occasionally I need to rely on a circular reliance of types where using and import are the only way to accomplish it.